# Pandas to_records() dtype conversion to char / unicode issue

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Pandas to_records() throws an error while numpy.array is behaving like expected.

```
data = [('myID', 5), ('myID', 10)]
myDtype = numpy.dtype([('myID', numpy.str_,4),
                       ('length', numpy.uint16)])
```

Working:

```
arr = numpy.array(data, dtype=myDtype)
output: [('myID',  5) ('myID', 10)]
```

This is not working

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.to_records(index=False, column_dtypes=myDtype)
```

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'myID'

What I am doing wroing with pandas to_records()?

Comment: What do you get if you omit `column_dtypes`?

Comment: Playing around, I find that `column_dtypes={'myID':'U4', 'length':'u2'}` works best.  The docs do say this parameter can be a `dict`.  It says nothing about being a `np.dtype`, though `myDtype.fields` is `dict` like.

Comment: I made my `df` from `arr`, not `data`, so the columns already had the matching names.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from what I understand, the way you wrote your variable `myDtype` isn't compatible with the column names your dataframe has.

Your current dataframe columns are int values of 0 and 1, causing your error (trying to match the int `0` to your naming `"myID"`).
(*Not entirely sure about that one so someone might want to complement, I'll edit the answer.*)

I was able to remove the error by referring the column_dtypes with a dictionary :

```py
    data = [("myID", 5), ("myID", 10)]
    myDtype = numpy.dtype([('myID', numpy.str_, 4),
                       ('length', numpy.uint16)])
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["myID", "length"])
    df_records = df.to_records(index=False, column_dtypes={"myID": "<U4", "length": "<u2"})
```

With the following result :

```py
rec.array([('myID',  5), ('myID', 10)],
          dtype=[('myID', '<U4'), ('length', '<u2')])
```

Answer (score 0):

`column_dtypes` argument in the `to_records()` function of a pandas `dataframe` expects a `dict` datatype as its input. But you are passing `myDtype` as the argument which is of type `numpy.dtype`.

Try this, it should work -

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["myID", "length"])
df_rec = df.to_records(index = False, column_dtypes = {"myID": "<U4", "length": "<u2"})
```

The output is -

```bash
>>> df_rec
rec.array([('myID',  5), ('myID', 10)],
          dtype=[('myID', '<U4'), ('length', '<u2')])
```